# Error occurs when trying to import sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I just tried to use `pip install sklearn` to install sklearn package(pydev3.4).  No errors occured during the installation, but when I test `import sklearn` in pydev, I get this error:

```
>>> import sklearn
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "H:\pydev3.4\lib\site-packages\sklearn__init__.py", line 57, in 
>       from .base import clone
>     File "H:\pydev3.4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 9, in 
>       from scipy import sparse
>     File "H:\pydev3.4\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse__init__.py", line 214, in 
>       from .csr import *
>     File "H:\pydev3.4\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csr.py", line 13, in 
>       from ._sparsetools import csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks, \
>   ImportError: Module use of python35.dll conflicts with this version of Python.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you install `sklearn` under Python 3.5 and then try to import it running Python 3.4?

Comment: First determine you python version `python -V` then determine your version compatibility with sklearn, then you'll probably need to uninstall and then reinstall the correct version